# Excel open remote file from url

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does Microsoft excel is able to open remote file `example.com/file.xlsx` ?

I mean file located in website without any athentification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is due to how windows works, and is not just something Microsoft excel has.

Whenever you have an open dialog, you can paste a URL into the filename box and hit Open. Explorer will then download the file to a temporary location and use that location to open the file.

This is similar as to how files are opened when they're attached in outlook. The file is first saved to a temporary location and then opened with excel.